# React useState: isActive and hasActivatedOnce states

Tags: reactjs, use-state

Say you have these 2 states:

```
const [ isActive ] = useState(false);
const [ hasActivatedOnce ] = useState(false);
```

`isActive` might track something like hover state of an element for example.
And then `hasActivatedOnce` would track if that element has been hovered/activated once. So it would turn `true` once, and then never turn `false`.

I'm trying to figure out a clean/performant way to update the `hasActivatedOnce` state based on the `isActive` state i.e. when `isActive` is set to `true`, `hasActivatedOnce` should be set to `true` (re-rendering the element only once of course).

Comment: You are missing your setState options, `const [isActive,setIsActive] = useState(false);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the face of it this would seem like a good use for [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

```
const [ isActive, setIsActive ] = useState(false);
const [ hasActivatedOnce, setHasActivatedOnce ] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (isActive) setHasActivatedOnce(true);
}, [isActive]);
```

This effect reacts to a changes in the `isActive` state and sets the second state when it is true. React bails out of identical state updates so we can safely update whenever `isActive` is true without triggering additional rerenders.

I think an effect hook is overkill here however and adds unnecessary complexity. You could just as well wrap both setters in one function and call that whenever `isActive` needs to change:

```
const setIsActiveWithEffect = (bool) => {
  setIsActive(bool);
  if (bool) setHasActivatedOnce(true);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use useEffect for that:

```
const [ isActive ] = useState(false);
const [ hasActivatedOnce, setHasActivatedOnce ] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    if (isActive) {
        setHasActivatedOnce(true);
    }
}, [isActive])
```

Multiple calls to "setHasActivatedOnce" with the same value won't trigger a render.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: How will he set isActive to false when something is not active?

Comment: @SanishJoseph OP didn't asked about how to set isActive, just how to set `hasActivatedOnce` when `isActive` changes

Comment: "isActive might track something like hover state of an element for example" from his question. That means, isActive needs to track both hover-on and hover -off.

Comment: @SanishJoseph Yes, but that wasn't the question: `I'm trying to figure out a clean/performant way to update the hasActivatedOnce state based on the isActive state`. Until OP expands its question I don't see why the discussion here anyway

Comment: Agreed. We don't know what exactly he needs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what's the difficulty in doing what you are asking. If I understand correctly you can achieve it like

```
const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
const [hasActivatedOnce, setHasActivatedOnce] = useState(false);
```

And in your JSX,

```
<div onMouseOver={()=>{setIsActive(true);setHasActivatedOnce(true)}} onMouseOut={()=>{
            setIsActive(false);
          }}>
            Something 
          </div>
```

JSX can be anything you like. Since you didn't provide any sample I just used a div

Answer (score 0):

An option could be using [useReducer](https://tr.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) hook. It's just like useState but it lets you do some complex operations such as calculations depending on the previous state.

What you need will be something like this:

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
  case 'activate':
    return {
       isActive: action.payload.isActive,
       hasActivated: action.payload.isActive || state.hasActivated
    };
  default:
    return state;
  }
};

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer,{isActive: false, hasActivated:false});

// Using in the component 
<button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'activate', payload:{isActive:true}})}>
```

If you have more values depending on each other or if you need some complex logic, you can use useReducer. Otherwise, I think the second solution in [the above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69050929/9208140) would work better.